# Working as IT engineer. Applied for bank clerk. Hiding details of previous employment

Tags: resignation, employer

I am working as a IT engineer for 5 years and now applied for bank clerk since I want to change the job profile from Private to govt.

Previously, I have cracked an exam of bank and they refused to select me on grounds that B.Tech + 4yr exp now why you want to join Bank clerk of lower grade?

So from there onward, I started applying to banks, without mentioning about my current employment. I can manage to clear exam and interview however I am fearing that after joining bank, is there any query from Income tax department or somewhere else it can be detected that I was previously employed somewhere?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I think India, "cracked an exam" suggests India.

Comment: What is the issue with being "discovered" after being hired? During the hiring process some people may argue against overqualified candidates, but once you have being hired it is actually moot (the risk they face with overqualiifed candidates is them resigning, and it would seem silly to fight that by firing you). So, what is the issue at hand?

Comment: And in any case, when such formal processes (exams and the like) are put in place, the middle managers opinion usually do not count much, so unless there is a law forbidding IT engineers from doing clerk job you should have nothing to worry about... could you please give more details about what is troubling you?

Comment: You seem to be asking how you can hide a 5 year employment history. **What you should be asking** is how you can convince the hiring manager that you really do want to take a step back in your career and will be happy in an entry-level position for 1-2 years.

Comment: If I were you, I would be more worried about explaining a 4+ year gap in your resume. For a bank clerk position, I'd think they would only check on your credit history and your criminal background (depending on the jurisdiction you'd be in). Of course, some will also probably google your name and take a look at your linkedin profile if they find it.

Comment: And yes, they may ask for your tax returns, but only if you did tell them you were self-employed during that period. If you told them you didn't earn any money, and that your parents/wife/husband paid for everything, or that you were a bum on the street, they wouldn't check obviously.

Comment: You must be having *some* reason for the question "why do you want to take up a bank job at a lower grade?". Have you tried telling that to them, maybe you weren't convincing enough, try to work on that, not trying to hide a 4+ year gap.

Answer (score 4):

> is there any query from Income tax department or somewhere else it can
>   be detected that I was previously employed somewhere?

These days, many hiring managers do a Google search for candidate's names. I always do.

> Please suggest.

Be honest.

Don't attempt to hide your past. Explain why it will be beneficial in your new position. Explain the motivation behind your desire to change careers. Explain how the lower pay grade isn't something that will bother you.

Comment: Joe has a point. Were you a lousy engineer? Did you not want to work 60-80 hours a week? Did your significant other not want you to work those hours? Did you miss interacting with people? All of these could be valid reasons for wanting to be a government bank clerk.